# Legal Considerations for Offering Rewards in Exchange for Tenant Selection in Germany

Tags: germany, real-estate, tenant, homeownership, money-service

My company and I are located in Germany and we intend to distribute flyers on the street. In the flyers, we offer a reward to those who are willing to rent out their homes in exchange for us being able to select the tenants (for example, offering 1500 euros). Subsequently, we plan to create a separate advertisement where we are seeking tenants for the house and asking for a higher amount of money (for example, 3000 euros). From a legal perspective, could such a practice be considered illegal? What aspects should we be mindful of?

Thank you!

Guten Tag,

Ich und mein Unternehmen sind in Deutschland ansässig und beabsichtigen, Flyer auf der Straße zu verteilen. In den Flyern bieten wir eine Belohnung (zum Beispiel 1500 Euro) für diejenigen an, die ihr Haus vermieten möchten, im Gegenzug dafür, dass wir die Mieter auswählen dürfen. Anschließend planen wir, eine separate Anzeige zu schalten, in der wir Mieter für das Haus suchen und einen höheren Geldbetrag verlangen (zum Beispiel 3000 Euro). Aus rechtlicher Sicht könnte eine solche Vorgehensweise illegal sein? Auf welche Aspekte sollten wir achten?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your question seems to ask for legal advice in a specific case. That would be off-topic. If you are asking strictly as a hypothetical:

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), there is supposed to be the *Bestellerprinzip* for services of a real state agent (whoever retains the agent pays the fees). This was clarified in the *Gesetz zur Regelung der Wohnungsvermittlung* [as changed in 2015](https://www.bmj.de/SharedDocs/Gesetzgebungsverfahren/Dokumente/BGBl_MietNovG.pdf;jsessionid=98F8CD0E5E340D8B5C3FC1D30997921C.2_cid324?__blob=publicationFile&v=6). Landlords and real estate agents are frequently trying to get around it, but getting the legal construction of the contracts wrong would mean a substantial fine.

Comment: But we are not real estate agents and we are simply talking about a Belohnung/Reward. Would this also fall under the Bestellerprinzip?
In Berlin, given the limited availability of apartments, it is very common to offer a Belohnung/Reward to the Vermieter/Landlord to become the house, we will only be the intermediaries.

Comment: Furthermore we will not be estate agents because we will pay the landlord to choose the tenant.

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo, you don't have to convince me, you have to convince the authorities. It may well be possible to write the contracts in a legal way, but it won't be easy. Being intermediaries *makes* you real estate agents, without the professional training, and there will be legal pitfalls.